# Unable to click element - Selenium Salesforce

Tags: java, selenium, salesforce

I'm trying to perform a click on a radio button using selenium on a salesforce webpage. I'm attaching an image of the page and inspecting the element

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OODfa.jpg

Every time i'm getting the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
```

I can perfectly locate the element on the page,`((//input[@type=\"radio\"][@value=\"IHT_Healthcare_Group\"])//parent::span)[1]"` but I got that error no matter what...

I have tried "Actions", but same result. Also, I tried

```
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) DriverManager.getDriver();
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", DriverManager.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("((//input[@type=\"radio\"][@value=\"IHT_Healthcare_Group\"])//parent::span)[1]")));
```

With that last one, it doesn't throw any error, but neither the click is performed.

Do you know what is happening here?

```
<fieldset>
  <span class="nds-form-element__legend nds-form-element__label nds-form-element__control-help nds-radio-relative-tooltip nds-show">
    <abbr title="required" class="slds-required">*</abbr>
    <span class="nds-m-right_x-small">Select Account Recordtype</span>
    <span class="nds-nowrap-whitespace">
      <slot name="label"></slot>
    </span>
  </span>
  <div class="nds-form-element__control nds-vertical_radio">
    <span class="nds-radio">
      <input type="radio" required="" id="vlocity-radio-0-0-247" data-index="0" name="vlocity-radio-0" value="IHT_Healthcare_Group">
      <label data-index="0" for="vlocity-radio-0-0-247" class="nds-radio__label">
        <span class="nds-radio_faux"></span>
        <span class="nds-form-element__label">Healthcare Group</span>
      </label>
    </span>
    <span class="nds-radio">
      <input type="radio" required="" id="vlocity-radio-0-1-247" data-index="1" name="vlocity-radio-0" value="IHT_Healthcare_Facility">
      <label data-index="1" for="vlocity-radio-0-1-247" class="nds-radio__label">
        <span class="nds-radio_faux"></span>
        <span class="nds-form-element__label">Healthcare Facility</span>
      </label>
    </span>
    <span class="nds-radio">
      <input type="radio" required="" id="vlocity-radio-0-2-247" data-index="2" name="vlocity-radio-0" value="IHT_Healthcare_Partner">
      <label data-index="2" for="vlocity-radio-0-2-247" class="nds-radio__label">
        <span class="nds-radio_faux"></span>
        <span class="nds-form-element__label">Healthcare Partner</span>
      </label>
    </span>
    <span class="nds-radio">
      <input type="radio" required="" id="vlocity-radio-0-3-247" data-index="3" name="vlocity-radio-0" value="IHT_Healthcare_Practitioner">
      <label data-index="3" for="vlocity-radio-0-3-247" class="nds-radio__label">
        <span class="nds-radio_faux"></span>
        <span class="nds-form-element__label">Healthcare Practitioner</span>
      </label>
    </span>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: You should be targeting either the label or the checkbox input itself.

Comment: Hi @ArundeepChohan, I tried both, but none is working and getting "element not interactable" :(

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: hI! @undetectedSelenium, thank you for your response. I'm updating with the html :)